# An installation package for the product Microsoft sharepoint foundation 2010 1033 lang pack can not be found

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, installation, language-pack

when I repair SharePoint 2010 I got below message from the wizard

> an installation package for the product Microsoft sharepoint foundation 2010 1033 lang pack cannot be found. try the installation again using a valid copy of the installation package wssmui.msi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually occurs in case you have installed the SharePoint from a specific location like `DVD Drive` that now does not exist during performing the repair!

If you remember from where you have installed the SharePoint, try to copy the same SharePoint version media to this location then start the Repair again!

**For example,** if you have installed the SharePoint from DVD drive so you should try to mount the same SharePoint version media to DVD drive then start Repair again.

If you don't remember the location path, there is a workaround to get it by doing the following:

- Search for `wssmui.msi' (the MSI that was shown in your error), right click on it > Select Repair.
- It should prompt to the original location of installation.
- Copy the path, then paste your SharePoint media there.
- Run the Repair again it should now be working.

Comment: Hi I am repairing from control panel programs and features , is I require sharepoint media even ?

Comment: Yes, it requires! Try to follow the above steps and feedback us with the result!

Comment: file was in this path C:\Program Files (x86)\MSECache\oserverlpk2010.ar-sa\wss.ar-sa when i search in all servers, here how can irepair the sharepoint

Comment: Right-click on the MSI file, then select repair, It should prompt to the original location of installation, copy the location path and cancel repair then paste your media at this original location and start repair again from CP or from the SP Media

Comment: @adilahmed what's your issue to apply this steps?